Full asymptotics near 1 of the generating function for integer partitions
Consider the generating function for integer partitions
$$
P(q)=\frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-q^k)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
p(n)q^n\ ,
$$
where $p(n)$ is the number of integer partitions of $n$.
I am interested in its behavior when $q\rightarrow 1^{-}$. More precisely, let
$$
f(t)=\ln P(e^{-t})
$$
and consider the full asymptotic expansion as $t\rightarrow 0^{+}$.
When working this out, I got
$$
f(t)\sim \frac{\pi^2}{6t}+\frac{1}{2}\ln t-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi)+\frac{t}{24}+O(t^{\infty})\ ,
$$
where $O(t^{\infty})$ means a function of $t$ which vanishes to infinite order when $t\rightarrow 0^{+}$.
However, in Exercise 3 of Chapter 3 of the book "Asymptotic Methods in Analysis", de Bruijn says
$$
f(t)\sim \frac{\pi^2}{6t}+\frac{1}{2}\ln t-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi)-\frac{t}{24}+O(t^{\infty})\ ,
$$
i.e., with the opposite sign for the term linear in $t$.
I have spent a ridiculous amount of time trying to find a sign error in my computations, and I feel I could use some help from the community of experts on this rather classical topic.
My question: Are there references where this de Bruijn exercise is worked out completely in detail? That would help me find, in comparison with my work, where the sign error might be.

Edit: I should have mentioned the references I already looked at, mostly gleaned from the article "Khinchin Families and Hayman Class" by Cantón et al. I have looked at the book by Flajolet and Sedgewick, the article "Hardy-Ramanujan's Asymptotic Formula for
Partitions and the Central Limit Theorem" by Báez-Duarte, as well as Section 3.2 of the original article by Hardy and Ramanujan. If there is no article or book with the wanted detailed calculation, I am kind of hoping that maybe someone taught, e.g., a course in analytic number theory and wrote that up as homework solutions for the students.

Edit 2: I finally found where my sign mistake was hiding. I will wait before accepting an answer. I already got two great explanations via modularity (by Mark), and complex variable methods using Mellin transforms (by Ofir). I am still hoping for an answer which addresses the real variable approach using Euler-Maclaurin which I guess is what de Bruijn had in mind.

From Dedekind's functional equation for $P(e^{-2\pi s})$ namely
$$ \log P(e^{-2\pi s}) - \log P(e^{-2\pi / s}) = \frac{\pi}{12}\left(\frac{1}{s}-s
\right) +  \frac{1}{2} \log s $$
we get
$$\log P(e^{-t}) = \frac{\pi^2}{6t} - \frac{t}{24} + \frac{1}{2} \log t - \frac{1}{2} \log 2\pi  + \log P(e^{-4\pi^2/t}). $$
The final term is $O(t^\infty)$. So the minus sign attached to $t/24$ by de Bruijn is correct. The functional equation is equivalent to the modularity of the Dedekind eta function so easily available in the literature. A comment since it's not a direct proof of de Bruijn.

@MarkWildon: thanks!

@MarkWildon: This is worth posting as an answer.

The purpose of this answer is twofold: i) give a reference to the derivation explained by Mark Wildon in his comment, ii) elaborate on a Mellin transform approach. I use your notation $P$ and $f$.

Let $q=e^{-2\pi \tau}$ where $\Re \tau >0$. Equation (5) in page 146 of R. Ayoub's book "An introduction to the analytic theory of numbers" (specifically Chapter III, Section 2 of the book) states that
$$P(q)=\psi(\tau)P(e^{-2\pi/\tau})$$
holds, where
$$\psi(\tau)=\sqrt{\tau}\exp\left[ \frac{\pi}{12}\left(\frac{1}{\tau}-\tau\right)\right].$$
If we let $t=2\pi \tau$, observe that
$$\log \psi(\tau) = \frac{\ln\frac{t}{2\pi}}{2} + \frac{\pi}{12}\left(\frac{2\pi}{t}-\frac{t}{2\pi}\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{6t} + \frac{1}{2}\ln t - \frac{1}{2}\ln (2\pi)  -\frac{t}{24}.$$
To conclude observe $P(e^{-2\pi/\tau})$ tends very rapidly to $1$ when $\tau \to 0$. This is discussed in page 146 as well.
The book is self-contained. Equation (5) is proved later in Section 3 as Theorem 3.2 (page 158). It is a quick consequence of Theorem 3.1 in that book, which describes the behavior of the Dedekind eta function $\eta(\tau)=q^{1/24}\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}(1-q^m)$ under modular transformation ($q=e^{2\pi i \tau}$, $\Im \tau>0$).

A Mellin transform approach is described in Lemma 6.1 (page 89) of G. E. Andrews' book "The theory of partitions" (1998 paperback edition). It does not give the linear term $-t/24$, and instead gives an error term of size $O(t^{C_0})$ for any choice of $C_0 \in (0,1)$. The result is, however, extremely general and in fact applies to a wide class of generating functions.
Specializing  equation (6.2.6) in the proof of Lemma 6.1 (page 90) to your problem, one finds
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty}t^{-s}\Gamma(s)\zeta(s+1)\zeta(s)\mathrm{d}s,$$
where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function.
Shifting the contour to the left, we see that Cauchy's residue theorem recovers the terms $\frac{\pi^2}{6t}$, $\frac{1}{2}\ln t$ and $-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi)$ as the residues of the integrand $t^{-s}\Gamma(s)\zeta(s+1)\zeta(s)$ at $s=1$ (where there is a simple pole) and $s=0$ (where there is a double pole). In other words, the constants $$\frac{\pi^2}{6},\qquad \frac{1}{2}, \qquad -\frac{1}{2}\ln (2\pi)$$
in the asymptotic formula actually arise as $$\zeta(2),\qquad -\zeta(0), \qquad \zeta'(0),$$ respectively.
This is as far as Andrews' book goes. We can easily go beyond in the special case that interests you, without the need of a new idea:
Recall $\Gamma$ has simple poles at $0$ and negative integers, and $\zeta$ vanishes at even negative integers. Hence $t^{-s}\Gamma(s)\zeta(s+1)\zeta(s)$ has no poles for $\Re s <0$ aside from a simple pole at $s=-1$. The linear term $-t/24$ is easily explained from the residue of the integrand $t^{-s}\Gamma(s)\zeta(s+1)\zeta(s)$ at $s=-1$. In other words, the constant $-1/24$ arises as
$$\mathrm{Res}(\Gamma,-1)\zeta(0)\zeta(-1) = -1 \times -\frac{1}{2} \times -\frac{1}{12}.$$
To prove that the remaining error is $O(t^{\infty})$ one should shift to $\Re s = -A$, and utilize the rapid decay of $\Gamma$ in vertical strips (together with the polynomial growth of $\zeta$ in such strips, e.g. using the functional equation and Stirling's approximation of $\Gamma$). Here $A>0$ is arbitrary.
The reason the book does not bother to recover the $-t/24$ term and the error term  is that it focuses on deriving a general result under mild conditions. In the setting of the book, the integrand is of the shape $t^{-s}\Gamma(s)\zeta(s+1)D(s)$ where $D$ satisfies two properties: it has an analytic continuation to $\Re s \ge -C_0$ for some $C_0 \in (0,1)$, and has polynomial growth in vertical strips.
It's interesting that the fact the $\zeta$ vanishes at negative even integers plays an important role here.

Much appreciated.

You could try looking at Flajolet--Sedgewick Analytic Combinatorics, p. 248, for further hints. They agree with the sign of de Bruijn.

I upvoted but unfortunately this does not at all answer my question. I should have mentioned the references I looked at already which include the FS classic book, and will edit my question accordingly. The issue is they just state the result and do not give details. Also, they state the remainder as $O(t^2)$ which I find suspicious. If they really did the exercise, they should have seen the remarkable cancellations that make this remainder $O(t^{\infty})$.

Sure, but the error $O(t^2)$ is at least good enough to check the sign you are interested in.

@SeanEberhard "The issue is they just state the result and do not give details."
